What was wrong with Tanilo?
In Juan Rulfo's short story "Talpa" (part of the collection The Burning Plain and Other Stories, of which George D. Schade's English translation is freely available to borrow from the Internet Archive), the narrator's brother Tanilo Santos is suffering from some kind of disease, which is never named but its symptoms are described:

From the day when he woke up with some purple blisters scattered about on his arms and legs. And later on the blisters became wounds that didn't bleed - just a yellow gummy thing like thick distilled water came out of them. From that time I remember very well he told us how afraid he was that there was no cure for him any more.

What is this condition? I guess it should be recognisable from the description, from those who know more about such things than I do. Is there really no cure for it, beyond the vain hope of a saintly miracle?

I would firstly introduce the standard disclaimer, which is that Juan Rulfo did not try to write realistic fiction. The disease that Tanilo was suffering from was a manifestation of a spiritual sickness, and so it need not correspond to any real-world ailment.
Nonetheless it is interesting to speculate if Rulfo could have had a real disease in mind. Little information about it is given in the short story, apart from the fact that it manifested as purple blisters on the skin of the arms and legs, which turned into sores that oozed a thick yellow liquid. We are also told that the course of the disease lasted for years, so it did not have quick mortality.
I have read a number of analyses of the story. Most do not attempt to identify the disease, but those that do generally settle on leprosy. For example, Manuel Quiroga Clérigo writes "Tanilo padece una enfermedad - quizá lepra" ("Tanilo suffers from an illness - possibly leprosy"); Mayda Bustamante concludes "La enfermedad de Tanilo se asemeja a las impurezas de la lepra" ("Tanilo's illness resembles leprosy"); Francisco Guzmán writes "La enfermedad sufrida por el protagonista, la cual no se precisa en el texto,  sugiere una infección en la piel, una especie de lepra" ("The illness the protagonist suffers from, although not specified in the text, suggests a skin infection, a type of leprosy"; and so on.
Leprosy certainly fits the spiritual aspect of the disease. Before the twentieth century it was essentially incurable and was regarded as a curse from God. Jesus' healing of the leper reflects the healing that Tanilo hoped to achieve by making a pilgrimage to the shrine of the Virgin of Talpa.
Leprosy is generally not characterised by the appearance of purple lesions, however. Usually it presents as hypopigmented patches of skin, lighter in color that their surroundings. There is, however, an unusual variant named Lucio's phenomenon, which is characterised by the appearance of "pupuras" (purple or red spots on the skin), which ulcerate and often become infected, producing brown-yellow pus. Several case studies are described here, which include descriptions like:

Multiple purpuras, hollow bullae filled with brown-yellow fluid, and
erosions on both arms, legs, and feet

which broadly fit the symptoms described by Rulfo. It is interesting that this variant is described as occurring "mainly in the Caribbean and Mexico, and rare in other parts of the world", possibly indicating how  Rulfo, living in Mexico, could have been aware of this variant.
